# How can I replace New map value by specific key On Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Here is the original data.

*Data format is List<Map<String, Any>>.*

```
#1
[
  {
    "item_id": "1234",
    "item_name": "MY ITEM 1",
    "origin_item_id": "NULL"
  },
  {
    "item_id": "9999",
    "item_name": "MY ITEM 5",
    "origin_item_id": "NULL"
  }
]
```

and Here is the new data that needs to be replaced.

```
#2
[
  {
    "item_id": "1111",
    "item_name": "CHANGE ITEM 1",
    "origin_item_id": "1234"
  }
]
```

first step) Get origin_item_id from #2 ("1234")

second step) Find item_id with "1234" in #1

third step) Replace #1's item_id : "1234" to #2(origin_item_id: "1234) data

And I should get the following result.

```
#3
[
  {
    "item_id": "1111",
    "item_name": "CHANGE ITEM 1",
    "origin_item_id": "1234"
  }
  {
    "item_id": "9999",
    "item_name": "MY ITEM 5",
    "origin_item_id": "NULL"
  }
]
```

How can I do this...?

Comment: Please explain the logic of the replacement here. Why is the first element in the original list got replaced with the new data?

Comment: Also, you should be using a list of a data class, instead of a list of maps. How about creating a data class to represent this data?

Comment: thanks ! I added the logic on my question.

Comment: and you said "List<Map<String, Any>> to List<_data class_> " ok i try this.

Comment: What should happen if the new data contains an `origin_item_id` that is not present in the old data? Should the new object be added to the list or what? What if the new data has objects with the same `origin_item_id`?

Answer (score 0):

To do the things asked in the question you could do this

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(
        mutableMapOf(
            "item_id" to "1234",
            "item_name" to "MY ITEM 1",
            "origin_item_id" to "NULL"
        ),
        mutableMapOf(
            "item_id" to "9999",
            "item_name" to "MY ITEM 5",
            "origin_item_id" to "NULL"
        )
    )
    val changes = listOf(
        mapOf(
            "item_id" to "1111",
            "item_name" to "CHANGE ITEM 1",
            "origin_item_id" to "1234"
        ),
    )

    changes.forEach { change ->
        list.forEach {
            if (it["item_id"] == change["origin_item_id"]) {
                it["origin_item_id"] = it["item_id"]!!
                it["item_id"] = change["item_id"]!!
                it["item_name"] = change["item_name"]!!
            }
        }
    }

    println(list)
}
```

But as suggested by Sweeper it's really better to work with data classes instead of maps

Answer (score -1):

With this solution, the new map replaces the previous one:

```
val originalList = listOf(
  mapOf(
    "item_id" to "1234",
    "item_name" to "MY ITEM 1",
    "origin_item_id" to "NULL"
  ),
  mapOf(
    "item_id" to "9999",
    "item_name" to "MY ITEM 5",
    "origin_item_id" to "NULL"
  )
)

fun main() {
    val changedList = originalList.map { originalMap ->
        if( originalMap["item_id"] == "1234" )
            mapOf(
                "item_id" to "1111",
                "item_name" to "CHANGE ITEM 1",
                "origin_item_id" to "1234"
            )  
        else originalMap
        // The map function checks the maps one by one.
        // If the conditions apply, the new map will replace the original one. 
        // Otherwise (else), the original one will be returned.
    }
    println(changedList)
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information in your answers to avoid being down voted.